# game loop delta time is not working with specified fps

Tags: javascript, time, frame-rate, game-loop, delta

Somehow `deltaTime` is usually 0.01667s (60fps) even though `targetFrameRate` is 30 (0.03333s), and yes `targetFrameRate` is working(adding delay). This makes movement code not work as intended with the specified fps when it is greater than or less than 60, making `velocity * deltaTime` broken.

Problem: `deltaTime` is always in 60fps and is not affected by `targetFrameRate`

Here's my code

```js
// Initializes the game loop
window.onload = () => {
    PlayerLoop.init();
};

// Gets called every frame
function Update ()
{
    console.log(Time.deltaTime);
}

// The specified fps
const targetFrameRate = 30;

// Class that holds time
class Time
{
    static unscaledTime = 0;
    static unscaledDeltaTime = 0;
    static timeScale = 1;
    static frameCount = 0;
    static time = 0;
    static deltaTime = 0;
    static maximumDeltaTime = 0.3333333;
}

// Game loop class
class PlayerLoop
{
    static #accumulator = 0;
    
    static #requestUpdate ()
    {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.#update.bind(this));
    }
    
    static #update ()
    {
        Time.unscaledDeltaTime = (performance.now() / 1000) - Time.unscaledTime;
        Time.unscaledTime += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
        
        var deltaT = Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
        
        if (deltaT > Time.maximumDeltaTime) deltaT = Time.maximumDeltaTime;
        
        Time.deltaTime = deltaT * Time.timeScale;
        Time.time += Time.deltaTime;
        
        this.#accumulator += Time.deltaTime;
        
        while (this.#accumulator >= 1 / (targetFrameRate))
        {
            Time.frameCount++;
            
            Update();
            
            this.#accumulator -= 1 / (targetFrameRate);
        }
        
        // Render
        
        this.#requestUpdate();
    }
    
    static init ()
    {
        this.#requestUpdate();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was supposed to write "s" lol, sorry

Comment: No problem, fixed it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it thanks to [Annas](https://twitter.com/AnnasVirtual)

My code was missing another delta time that will tell when to update the global `Time.deltaTime` variable

Here's My New Code

```js
// Initializes the game loop
window.onload = () => {
    PlayerLoop.init();
};

// Gets called every frame
function Update ()
{
    console.log(Time.deltaTime);
}

// The specified fps
const targetFrameRate = 30;

// Class that holds time
class Time
{
    static unscaledTime = 0;
    static unscaledDeltaTime = 0;
    static timeScale = 1;
    static frameCount = 0;
    static time = 0;
    static deltaTime = 0;
    static maximumDeltaTime = 0.3333333;
}

// Game loop class
class PlayerLoop
{
    static #requestUpdate ()
    {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.#update.bind(this));
    }
    
    static #update ()
    {
        // Frame rate - anti delay value
        const slice = (1 / targetFrameRate) - 0.005;
        
        // This is the "other delta time"
        let accumulator = (performance.now() / 1000) - Time.unscaledTime;
        
        while (accumulator >= slice)
        {
            Time.unscaledDeltaTime = (performance.now() / 1000) - Time.unscaledTime;
            Time.unscaledTime += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
            
            let deltaT = Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
            
            if (deltaT > Time.maximumDeltaTime) deltaT = Time.maximumDeltaTime;
            
            Time.deltaTime = deltaT * Time.timeScale;
            Time.time += Time.deltaTime;
            
            Time.frameCount++;
            
            Update();
            
            accumulator -= slice;
        }
        
        // Render
        
        this.#requestUpdate();
    }
    
    static init ()
    {
        this.#requestUpdate();
    }
}
```

I have removed `PlayerLoop.#accumulator` and added `accumulator` as the "other delta time". Then I moved all of the `Time` update code to the inside of the while loop.

Thank you for everyone who helped